# Как в С++ вызвать шаблонную функцию напрямую? [обновлено]

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Добрый день.

Пусть есть шаблонная функция (примеры не транслировал):

```
template <class T> T fun(T s1, T s2){return s1+s2;}
```

Теперь, чтобы получить разные функции, можно сделать так:

```
char fun1(char s1, char s2){return fun<char>(s1,s2);}

int fun2(int s1, int s2){return fun<int>(s1,s2);}

float fun3(float s1, float s2){return fun<float>(s1,s2);}
```

Однако, если бы я написал эти функции не через шаблон, то я бы съэкономил один вызов:

```
char fun1(char s1, char s2){return s1+s2;}

int fun2(int s1, int s2){return s1+s2;}

float fun3(float s1, float s2){return s1+s2;}
```

Вопрос:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы в случае шаблонной функции не было лишнего вызова? То есть синтаксически это должно выглядеть так, что при инстанцировании шаблона функции имя функции тоже менялось. И инстанцированный шаблон получал новое имя fun1, fun2, fun3 вместе с параметром-типом аргумента.

Спасибо.

UPD1:

Дотошные коллеги убедили меня уточнить проблему. Действительно, приведенный пример упрощен, по сравнению с жизнью. Тем не менее даже пример показывает всю проблему, хотя, возможно, и не так очевидно. Уточним пример. Итак, на самом деле есть шаблон функции с параметром шаблона - указателем на другую функцию (примеры не транслировал).

```
template <typename float (*libfun)(float)> int myfun(int a1,float a2,double a3){

float res=libfun(a2);

//здесь много обработки, одинаковой для всех libfun

return ret;
}
```

теперь инстанцируем шаблон:

```
int ret1=myfun<&sin>(1,2,3);
int ret2=myfun<&cos>(1,2,3);
int ret3=myfun<&exp>(1,2,3);
```

Вроде бы все на месте. Проблема в том, что на самом деле мне нужны нешаблонные функции с одинаковым прототипом:

```
int mysin(int a1,float a2,double a3);
int mycos(int a1,float a2,double a3);
int myexp(int a1,float a2,double a3);
```

При этом функции mysin, mycos, myexp **должны вызываться из сторонней библиотеки callback-ом**. Поэтому они не могут быть шаблонными и должны иметь именно такой прототип.

Можно сделать так (как собственно и сделано в первом примере):

```
int mysin(int a1,float a2,double a3){return myfun<&sin>(a1,a2,a3);}
int mycos(int a1,float a2,double a3){return myfun<&cos>(a1,a2,a3);}
int myexp(int a1,float a2,double a3){return myfun<&exp>(a1,a2,a3);}
```

Но при этом получается лишний вызов.

Итак, снова тот же вопрос:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы в случае шаблонной функции не было лишнего вызова? То есть синтаксически это должно выглядеть так, что при инстанцировании шаблона функции имя функции тоже менялось. И инстанцированный шаблон получал новое имя mysin, mycos, myexp вместе с параметром-типом аргумента.

Comment: А зачем писать три разных функции когда уже есть шаблон? При инстанцировании шаблона функции имя функции и так меняется, получаются функции `fun<char>`, `fun<int>` и т.д. Если нужны просто три разные функции, то зачем шаблон? С чего вы взяли, что в случае вызова шаблонной функции из обычной реально будет лишний вызов?

Comment: У вас какой-то сверхискусственный пример. В **таком** варианте вам действительно не нужна шаблонная функция. Но стоит представить, что она делает, скажем так, несколько побольше - строк на 20 кода - как картина сразу меняется, правда? А изменение имени... Оно и так меняется - декорированное :) Опять же - зачем вам нужны эти разные имена? Это не [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)?

Comment: Лишнего вызова не будет, если компилятор посчитает, что встроить функцию имеет смысл. Скорее всего, он посчитает.

Comment: Функции `myfun` и `mysin`, `mycos` имеют одинаковую сигнатуру. Специализации `myfun` можно без проблем использовать в качестве колбека. Кроме того, пример шаблона должен быть без `typename`, так как он не является типом. `template <float ( * libfun )(float)>`

Comment: Хм, действительно оказалось что инстанцированный шаблон имеет такой же прототип, несмотря на все пляски с маскарингом имен. И этот инстанцированный шаблон можно вставлять в вызов callback и транслятор это понимает. Кто бы мог подумать. Спасибо. А шаблон работает и с typename и без typename. Транслятор Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не заморачиваться:

```
auto fun(auto s1, auto s2) {
    return s1 + s2;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << fun(std::string("A"), "B") << std::endl;
}
```

Можно взять ссылку:

```
auto constexpr f = fun<std::string>;
```