# Как в С++ вызвать шаблонную функцию напрямую? [продолжение]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день.

Я уже задавал похожий вопрос [вот ссылка на мой старый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776659/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%A1-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE), и снова он возник.

Итак, есть код:

```
#define OPERATIONWRAPPER(name)                         \
void name(ob_savewrapper* a){                             \
var* tmpptr=ptr->name##_v(a->ptr);                     \
if(tmpptr==ptr){ a->clear();} else {clear();transfer(a);} \
}

    //some realization
    class savewrapper {
        var* ptr;
    public:
        savewrapper() :ptr(NULL) {}
        savewrapper(var* p) :ptr(p) {}

        void setptr(var* s) {
            if ((ptr != NULL) && (s != NULL)) {
                clear();//for eliminate double delete
                ERR(ob_err78)
            }//if
            ptr = s;
        }

        void clear() { delete ptr; ptr = NULL; }
        ~savewrapper() { delete ptr; }

        void transfer(savewrapper* d) {
            setptr(d->ptr);
            d->setptr(NULL);
        }

        OPERATIONWRAPPER(add);
        OPERATIONWRAPPER(sub);
        OPERATIONWRAPPER(mul);
        OPERATIONWRAPPER(div);
        OPERATIONWRAPPER(pww);

    };
```

Здесь есть иерархия классов, в которой класс var является базовым.
Класс savewrapper это обертка над классами этой иерархии.
В классах иерархии есть функции add_v, sub_v, mul_v, div_v, pww_v.
В классе savewrapper должны быть функции add, sub, mul, div, pww, в которых вызываются соответствующие функции из классов иерархии var.

Сейчас это сделано через макрос, как видно в примере. Но я хочу быть передовым программистом, и поэтому я решил переделать макрос в шаблон. Пишу шаблон:

```
template<var* (var::*method)(var* ptr1)> inline void operation_wrapper(savewrapper* a) {
            var* tmpptr = (ptr->*method)(a->ptr);

            if (tmpptr == ptr) {
                a->clear();
            }
            else {
                clear();
                transfer(a);
            }
        }
```

Инстанцирую шаблон для примера для метода add:

```
void add(savewrapper* a) { operation_wrapper<&(var::add_v)>(a); }
```

Все даже работает, но есть лишний вызов по сравнению с решением на основе макроса. А именно, хотя шаблон объявлен как inline, но инлайн не гарантируется компилятором. А если шаблон будет не инлайн, то будет лишний вызов функции, по сравнению с решением на основе макроса.

Вопрос:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы не было лишнего вызова функции? Имя add для метода класса savewrapper должно сохраниться, так как во многих местах оно используется и подставлять по всему коду вместо add явный вызов шаблона

   operation_wrapper<&(var::add_v)>(a);

это очень плохой вариант.

Спасибо.

UPD1:

Вобщем, как не крути, но получается что для шаблонов функций нужно иметь еще одну возможность. А именно, при инстанцировании шаблона функции нужно иметь возможность дать получившейся функции новое имя. Иначе шаблоны проигрывают по гибкости макросам.

Comment: Избавьтесь от макросов и шаблонов, вынесите блок `if` в отдельную функцию либо вынесите все тело метода в отдельную функцию (не шаблонную), принимающую указатель на метод как аргумент.

Comment: Такой вариант тоже теряет в производительности по сравнению с макросом, потому что при этом варианте в функцию дополнительно передается указатель на функцию, а на копирование этого указателя затрачивается время. Получается, что вариант с макросом более производителен чем любые другие варианты.

Comment: И да, такой вариант даже хуже чем шаблон, так как и лишний вызов есть и явная передача указателя на функцию add_v тоже есть.